# How can I get the source code of a file from GitWeb?

Tags: git, gitweb

I want to download (via curl or AJAX) the HEAD revision of a file in a Git repository. GitWeb is already installed.

I can get the formatted source code:
http://server1.local/?p=Project&a=blob&f=Path/To/File.html

However, this does not seem to work when I use blob_plain as the value for "a"; blob_plain requires a hash in a "h" parameter - but I want to refer to the newest version of the file, not a specific one.

Is there something that needs to be configured? Am I using the right URL schema?

Answer (score 1):

Which gitweb version?

Because it works for me.  When I can access

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi/git.git?a=blob;f=builtin/annotate.c
```

i can also access

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi/git.git?a=blob_plain;f=builtin/annotate.c
```

---

You can always try to give `HEAD` as argument to 'hb', i.e.

```
http://server1.local/?p=Project&a=blob&f=Path/To/File.html&hb=HEAD
```

Comment: That what was I thought - but the server gives me an HTTP 500 when I combined blob_plain with h=HEAD...

I've got an appointment with the admin tomorrow, let's see what he says.

Comment: @GreenIcicle: I am very sorry, it should be **'hb'** (hash *base*), not 'h' (fixed now)... assuming that given file is present in HEAD (but if 'blob' action works, then it should be present).  BTW it is important _which_ of HTTP 500 responses was that (error message shown on page).